# Change eclipse template for setter so that actual parameter be named 'value'?

Tags: java, eclipse, setter, code-templates

I want setters coded like this:

```
private String name;

public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}
```

but if I program eclipse template like this

```
${field} = value;
```

I get the following wrong code:

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = value;
}
```

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

My configuration as below:

```
${field} = ${param};
```

Comment: Yes this is default configuration. It generates formal parameter name which is not `value` but the same as backing variable name. I wish to change this.

Comment: in comments its used as ${bare_field_name}  but it does not exist for  body template as a variable. Maybe you will be interested with this link for how to add a new variable: http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/use-your-own-variable-in-eclipse-code-templates/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to accomplish this as you can only influence the body of the setter, not the signature.